# Filter for child array is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

facing issue is that when we check checkboxes.. only checked items have to be selected in an array.. i have used filter to acheive.. but filter for child arrays are not working. able to get values whatever the parent array is checked.. but for child arrays all the arrays are showing.

Component Code Here

```js
export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {
  checkedList: any=[];
  capRat: any=[];
  xyzlist = [
    {
      id: 1,
      value: 'option1',
      child:[
        {
          cid: 101,
          childname: "ramu"
        },
        {
          cid: 102,
          childname: "raghu"
        },
        {
          cid: 103,
          childname: "rosy"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 'option2',
      child:[
        {
          cid: 201,
          childname: "somu"
        },
        {
          cid: 202,
          childname: "sundar"
        },
        {
          cid: 203,
          childname: "suraj"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 'option3',
      child:[
        {
          cid: 301,
          childname: "jaddu"
        },
        {
          cid: 302,
          childname: "veeru"
        },
        {
          cid: 303,
          childname: "hyder"
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  a: any=[];
  fArr: any=[];
  constructor() {
    this.a =  this.xyzlist.map((el)=>{
    let child = el.child.map(cel=>({...cel, checked:false}));
    return {...el, checked: false, child}
    })
    console.log(this.a);
    //this.capRatTest(); 
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  // capRatTest(){
  //   this.capRat=this.xyzlist
    
  // }

  onCheckboxChange(option, event) {
    // if(event.target.checked) {
    //   this.checkedList.push(option.id);
    // } else {
    //   for(var i=0 ; i < this.xyzlist.length; i++) {
    //     if(this.checkedList[i] == option.id){
    //       this.checkedList.splice(i,1);
    //     }
    //   }
    // }
    option.checked = !option.checked;
    option.child.forEach(el=> {
      if(option.checked){
        el.checked = true
      } else{
        el.checked = false
      }
    })
    this.filterArr()
  }

  onCheckboxChildChange(option, event) {
   option.checked = !option.checked
   this.filterArr()
    }
    
  filterArr(){
  this.fArr =   this.a.filter(el=>{
        console.log(el);
           let child1 = el.child.filter(el_ => el_.checked == true); 
      el = {...el, child1};
      
     return el.checked == true;
     
     
    });

    console.log(this.fArr);
  }

}

HTML Code Here
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let list of a">
    <ul>
    <label>
      <input  type="checkbox" value="{{list.id}}" [checked]="list.checked" (change)="onCheckboxChange(list,$event)">{{list.value}}</label>
    <li>
      <label *ngFor = "let item of list.child">
        <input  type="checkbox" value="{{item.id}}"  [checked]="item.checked" (change)="onCheckboxChildChange(item,$event)">{{item.childname}}</label>
    </li>
    
    </ul>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have to do a lot of changes to achieve what you want.**

**Change your `onCheckboxChildChange()` method as below.**

```
  onCheckboxChildChange(option, event) {

      option.checked = !option.checked
      if (option.checked) {
        let parent = this.a.filter(p => {
          let child = p.child.filter(c => {
            return c.checked === true;
          });
          return child.length > 0 ? true: false;
        });
        parent[0].checked = true;
      }
      this.filterArr()
  }
```

**To `filterArr()` you need to use both `forEach` and `filter`.**

```
  filterArr(){
    this.fArr = []
    this.a.forEach(parent => {
      if (parent.checked) {
        let tempParent = {...parent};
        let tempChild = tempParent.child.filter(c => {
          return c.checked === true;
        });
        tempParent.child = tempChild;
        this.fArr.push(tempParent)
      }
    });
    // Chage fArr to [] if there is not any checkbox is checked
    let tempArr = this.a.filter(p => p.checked === true);
    if (tempArr.length === 0) {
      this.fArr = []
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fArr, null, 2));
  }
```

**Hope this is what you are expecting. Find [Stackblitz Example Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw9mvx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Hii, thanks for the reply, it is working, but in the result array the previous checkbox result also showing.. how to eliminate that?

Comment: should not result array contain all the checked checkboxes values ?

Comment: it should show only the values which is checked.. it is showing previous checkbox triggered  values along with present checkbox values..

Comment: Actually I did not get you. It is showing all the checked checkboxes values. is it not your requirement.

Comment: I did  a change to my stackblitz demo. check whether is it ok

Comment: wow!.. your'e awesome... it works perfect! thanks for your help.. can you please tell me what you did there?

Comment: initialize `fArr` to empty array at the start of `filterArr()`. I will update my answer

Comment: If my answer is ok with you please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: ok.. how it will be done.. clicking tick mark under feedback votes right? if yes.. its done!